# Exclude element from JQuery-UI containment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to allow an element to be dragable/resizable inside of another element but not in the area of another child of that element.

Given the following table row:
[image: table row with blue area spanning three columns and the fifth column greyed out]

I want to be able to drag and resize the blue area anywhere within the table row, but not where the grey table cell is (i.e. it would move/resize freely within the first four cells but be stopped when it reaches the last one).

I can constrain it to the table row using the `containment: '.middle tr'` or `containment: $el.closest('tr'),` (where `$el` is a selector for the blue element) options in `JQuery.draggable` and `JQuery.resizable`, but I haven't been able to find a way that works for excluding the last column from the containment.

**How do you exclude an element from the containment area?**

Example with code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggable = ui.draggable;

      var newLeft = draggable.offset().left - draggable.closest(".middle table").offset().left;
      var childNum = Math.round((newLeft + 100) / 100);

      var newContainer = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(' + childNum + ')');

      draggable.css({
        top: '',
        left: ''
      });

      newContainer.append(draggable);
    },
  });
  $(".planning-spot").resizable({
    grid: [100, 10000000],
    handles: "e",
    containment: ".middle tr"
  }).each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.draggable({
      containment: $el.closest('tr'),
      axis: 'x',
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
}

td, th {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.planning-spot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 290px;
  background: #3CF;
}

.no-planning {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="middle">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div></div>
              <div class="planning-spot">18 / 20</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="no-planning">
              <div></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/668937/

I'm aware that I can check the location during the `drop` and `stop` functions of `droppable` and `resizable` respectively and reverse the action if needed (which is my current solution), but I'm looking for a solution to prevent it being moved into an "unwanted" area in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the draggable area with `getBoundingClientRect()` and assign containment to an array wich take the width of each resizeable elements

```js
$(function() {

  $("td").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggable = ui.draggable;

      var newLeft = draggable.offset().left - draggable.closest(".middle table").offset().left;
      var childNum = Math.round((newLeft + 100) / 100);

      var newContainer = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(' + childNum + ')');

      draggable.css({
        top: '',
        left: ''
      });

      newContainer.append(draggable);
    },
  });
  $(".planning-spot").resizable({
    grid: [100, 10000000],
    handles: "e",
    containment: ".middle tr"
  }).each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var bBoxTr = $el.closest('tr')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var bBoxTd = $el.closest('tr').children(".no-planning")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var x1 = bBoxTr.x, y1 = bBoxTr.y;
    var x2 = bBoxTr.right-bBoxTd.width, y2 = bBoxTr.bottom;
    $el.draggable({
//      containment: $el.closest('tr'),
      containment: [x1,y1,x2-$el.width()-10,y2],
      axis: 'x',
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: no-collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
}

td, th {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.planning-spot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 290px;
  background: #3CF;
}

.no-planning {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="middle">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="test">
            <td>
              <div></div>
              <div class="planning-spot">18 / 20</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="no-planning">
              <div></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Since `getBoundingClientRect();` is not supported by all browsers, better go with jquery features, `position()`, `height()` and `width();`.

See the revised snippet below, the function `getDragArea` returns an array with the coordinates of the drag area. I add a listener (mouseover) which permit to reset drag area when needed. 
The table is wrapped in a scrolling div to test behavior.

```js
$(function() {

  $("td").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggable = ui.draggable;

      var newLeft = draggable.offset().left - draggable.closest(".middle table").offset().left;
      var childNum = Math.round((newLeft + 100) / 100);

      var newContainer = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(' + childNum + ')');

      draggable.css({
        top: '',
        left: ''
      });

      newContainer.append(draggable);
    },
  });
  $(".planning-spot").resizable({
    grid: [100, 10000000],
    handles: "e",
    containment: ".middle tr"
  }).each(function() {
    $(this).on('mouseover',function(){
      $(this).draggable({
      containment: getDragArea($(this)),
      axis: 'x',
    });
 })
  });
  
 function getDragArea($el){
    var $tr = $el.closest('tr');
   var $tds = $el.closest('tr').children(".no-planning");
   var width = $el.closest('tr').width()-$tds.width()*$tds.length;
   var height = $el.closest('tr').height();
    var position = $el.closest('tr').position();
    var x1 = position.left, y1 = position.top;
    var x2 = x1+width, y2 = y1+height;
    return [x1,y1,x2-$el.width()-10,y2]
   }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: no-collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
}

td, th {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.planning-spot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 290px;
  background: #3CF;
}

.no-planning {
  background: #CCC;
}

.wrapper{
  overflow:auto;
  width:500px;
  height:120px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="middle">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="test">
            <td>
              <div></div>
              <div class="planning-spot">18 / 20</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="no-planning">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="no-planning">
              <div></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works well for dragging! What are the coordinates from `getBoundingClientRect()` relative to? For instance, if it's used in a table that scrolls (vertically and horizontally) do you know if it would still work as expected?

Comment: [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) returns position relative to the viewport, therefore it should work except for negative values

Comment: You can also run with `position()`, as `getBoundingClientRect` is not supported by IE and Safari

Answer (score 1):

I did the trick by checking if drag event will cause collision with non dragable item.

Checkout code below:

```js
$(function() {
 var nonDragableItems = $(".no-planning");
  $("td").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggable = ui.draggable;

      var newLeft = draggable.offset().left - draggable.closest(".middle table").offset().left;
      var childNum = Math.round((newLeft + 100) / 100);

      var newContainer = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(' + childNum + ')');

      draggable.css({
        top: '',
        left: ''
      });

      newContainer.append(draggable);
    },
  });
  
  function onDrag(e, ui){
    var dragElemRect = ui.helper[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    for(var i=0;i<nonDragableItems.length;i++){
      var elemRect = nonDragableItems[i].getBoundingClientRect();
      if(areColliding(dragElemRect, elemRect))
        return false;
    }
  }

  function areColliding(rect1, rect2){
    if(rect1.bottom <= rect2.top ||
       rect1.top >= rect2.bottom ||
       rect1.left >= rect2.right ||
       rect1.right <= rect2.left)
          return false;
        return true;
  }
  
  $(".planning-spot").resizable({
    grid: [100, 10000000],
    handles: "e",
    containment: ".middle tr"
  }).each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.draggable({
      containment: $el.closest('tr'),
      axis: 'x',
      drag: onDrag
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
}

td, th {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.planning-spot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 290px;
  background: #3CF;
}

.no-planning {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="middle">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div></div>
              <div class="planning-spot">18 / 20</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="no-planning">
              <div></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Impressive, the only problem I see with this method is that when it finds a collision it drops the draggable element so that, in this case, if you drag it all the way to the right (where the non-draggable element is) then you can't drag it back to the left unless you let go of the mouse and pick it back up again. I'll look into it more when I get to work tomorrow, but it looks like this answer is on the right track

Comment: I'd also like a solution that works for resizing as well